# How to perform a load testing for the following use cases

Tags: performance, load, performance-testing, load-testing

I have my site running inside a server behind my cope firewall. I need some libraries that will give me some insights on load testing. Specifically I need.

1. Provide results for the maximum concurrent tests the platform can support at this time.
2. Steps to scale the application to 20 concurrent tests.
3. Provide results for the maximum tests per day the platform can support at this time.
4. Steps to scale the application to minimum 10000 tests per day.
5. What is report generation time to load ratio.

Is there some open source APIs that can give me some insights on the above points

Comment: By saying 20 concurrent tests you mean 20 users using application? or something else?

Comment: Yes same as 20 usres

Comment: have you heard of JMeter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use cases include Performance testing as well as tuning part.

Performance engineering (testing + tuning + reporting) is big task. Which depends on system under test, SLAs defined, possible bottlenecks, optimizations and it takes time/experience to do all these things.

For use cases :

```
1. Provide results for the maximum concurrent tests the platform can support at this time.
2. Steps to scale the application to 20 concurrent tests.
3. Provide results for the maximum tests per day the platform can support at this time
```

Load testing and Stress testing is required. **JMeter** is an open source tool written in Java which can used for Load testing and stress testing which will help you to find max capacity of server today. Please have a look at [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) and tutorial for building test plan [Building Test plan in JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)

```
4. Steps to scale the application to minimum 10000 tests per day
```

Performance tuning is required to scale appliation to 10000 users per day if it doesn't match the required SLA. Performance testing results will help to identify possible bottlenecks in system which you should try to improve.

1. DB - add indexes, tune parameters, improve query, partition DB etc.
2. App Server - tune server config, caching, connection pool, code improvement, logging etc.

Similarly other tiers should be looked at and improved performance.

```
5. What is report generation time to load ratio.
```

Generally testing and data setup take more time than analysis and resolution. many freewares are available for JMeter result/log analysis.

In addition, Paid tools like **Load Runner, Rational Performance Tester, Selenium** etc. are also present for load testing. I prefer JMeter because of its simplicity and configurability. (lot of support is present with custom plugins)

I hope this was helpful.